# Unable to copy actual files on remote using git-annex

Tags: git, git-annex

I currently want to deploy my existing `git-annex` repository on a new computer.

My configuration is the following one:

- on `serverA`: I have a `git bare` (with git-annex) repository and no actual files
- on `serverB`: I have an classical `git-annex` local folder which contains the actual (heavy) files (synced with `serverA`'s repository)
- on `serverC`: I want to create a new git-annex repository and copy the files from `serverB` on it

Notice that I am not able to clone directly from `serverB`on `serverC`.

I follow the process:

- on `serverC`: `git clone ssh://serverA/<path>` after I run  `git annex init origin` and `git annex sync`
- on `serverB`: `git remote add NEW ssh://serverC/<path>`, `git annex sync NEW` and it works. But when I want to copy the actual (heavy) files using `git annex sync NEW --content`, no file are copied and I have for each file the following error: `copy <file> (unable to check NEW) failed`.

Any idea of the raeson of these errors (notice that debug mode provide no additional information)?

Notice that all servers use version 8.xx of `git-annex`

Comment: The `unable to check NEW` is the clear important element here.  I don't remember if that means it can't check because it can't connect or something else.  Have you done a `git fetch NEW` to make sure that works alone (I think `git annex sync` does this for you, but running it explicitly may give you more clues)

Comment: @WesHardaker thank you for your reply. I run `git fetch NEW` but it changes nothing...

Comment: Have you tried `git annex copy SOMETHING -to NEW` to see if you can manually copy them over there?

Comment: Yes, and it fails with same error

Comment: This is beginning to sound familiar...  have you done a `git pull` from NEW?  You may need to update the annex branch on NEW manually (I know you've said you can't actually do a pull).

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is that serverC still doesn't know about the remote B.  Even if you never expect to access B directly, serverC still needs to set up a remote to B for annex to recognize it exists.  maybe.

Comment: I am very surprised of it because git annex sync NEW works well.

Comment: @WesHardaker I think you are right concerning the identification of each repository. `git annex` identify each repo using a uuid. The use of an intermediate `bare` repo leads to not provide the uuid of serverB on serverC. So, if you want to copy file from serverB to serverC, serverB runs a command (using ssh) `git annex shell p2pstdio <pathOnC> --uuid <uuidofB>` which return that uuidofB is not known..........

Comment: Notice that this trouble can be solved by changing the uuid in serverC with the corresponding one on the git config on serverB remote declaration.